# Installing Ubuntu on another Hard Drive Disk (F:)

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows-xp

I want to install Ubuntu side by side on my Windows XP.But instead of placing it on HDD C: drive, i want to place it on a slave HDD (which would be drive F:).I already tested on a virtual machine in placing on a second HDD but it doesn't appear to work.
How should i proceed?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? What happens and when?

Comment: I mean "trial and failure" could not get it on the secondary HDD

Comment: It says "no root file, correct it on the partition menu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:
As we discovered my answer is not that relevant if you use Wubi as it will do all the complicated work for you. But if somebody reading this plans to do it with grub instead then keep reading.

---

The problem with such setup is that it makes bootloader setup bit more difficult.
Namely when you want to boot to XP then Windows requires to be on the first boot device. The problem is that grub (Linux bootloader that usually would provide the menu at boot where you can chose which OS you want to start) is installed on the second HD where Ubuntu is and if you boot to grub (that is, use the HD where Ubuntu is as the first boot drive) and chose Windows then it won't start.

---

Remember that /dev/sda, /dev/sdb... are just names that the drives have in Linux. Windows knows nothing about it and neither does bios. Windows uses names such as C:, D: ..but neither does know Linux or bios about them. What matters here is boot order set in [bios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS). For changing the boot order in bios [there are lot of guides available](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=bios%20boot%20order&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=et&gs_rn=12&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=rtD8mjL4GQwDMTEYSv91Ag&pq=bios%20boot%20order&cp=4&gs_id=1t9&xhr=t&q=change%20bios%20boot%20order&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=ubuntu&hs=IUJ&channel=fs&biw=1280&bih=868&sclient=psy-ab&oq=chanbios%20boot%20order&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.bGE&fp=e305b0e1bc7ab9a5) and it is dependent on your hardware model.

---

What you need to do is to set up XP bootloader to let you chose between Ubuntu and Windows.
There is a good guide for it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader). I have not tested it myself but you should get general idea and what keywords to search for. In your case Ubuntu would be installed on a separate HD and in theory you should not be worried about overwriting Windows MBR. Of course it doesn't hurt to unplug Windows HD before you install Ubuntu just to make sure nothing funny happens during the installation.

Comment: What if i let the bootloader on /dev/sdb ?Will it work?

Comment: Hello?You still online?

Comment: Don't be needy.

Comment: At least answer me?

Comment: I edited my answer and all the new information is there. Or do you have new questions?

Comment: Marco Ceppi said Wubi does that.Does it?

Comment: Does what? Make changes to Windows bootloader? I don't know. I have never used Wubi.

Comment: Wubi is inside the disc of ubuntu install.

Comment: Well i just saw that Wubi thing at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-with-windows. i guess intalling ubuntu will be much easier using this.
Sorry i answered my own question :P

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that Ubuntu will not list your drives as C: D: etc. but will refer to them as /dev/sda, /dev/sdb, etc.

> **Please make a backup of your important data to be able to restore them if anything fails by accident**

Boot the CD, and start the installation.  Once you get to the installation screen, choose Something else

[image]

Choose the second Drive

[image]

After you choose it, click on Create new partition table, and just follow the rest of the steps, as shown in the images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shoudn't "Device for boot loader" be /dev/sdb ?

Comment: The reason its `sda` and not `sdb` is because of where and how Grub 2 writes the information.

Comment: Also, when i try in a larger scale (Slave is 20 GB and Master 300 GB) what should be the proportion on the slave file for ext4 partition and swap area?

Comment: Normally swap is recommended to be equal to the amount of RAM.

Comment: is there any pattern for ext4 partition?

Comment: Uh...Drat.An error occured and it's not possible to place the bootloader on /dev/sda

Comment: What do you mean a pattern?

Comment: What error? Can you add the info from the error?

Comment: By pattern i mean what must be place on ext4 part when i have intel dual core 2.0 Ghz,2GB Ram,Intel GMA video card and windows xp on Master whit 147 free space and a fully free F:/ file.

Comment: And it said that something did not let the bootloader to be on dev/sdz

Comment: For that you might want to look at [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition)

Comment: Showed again the error(executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed.This is an fatal error)

Comment: Take a look at the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u) here

Comment: Let me know what's going on, and if you need more help.

Comment: Is everything working OK? Has the problem been solved?

Comment: Yeah probably.Let me just format my F: HDD