# Can not boot from SSD on Samsung NP530U4C

Tags: grub2, partitioning, ssd

I wanted to install Ubuntu for my Samsung NP530U4C on SSD. There are 2 drives available in this machine one is 750 GB HDD and 24 GB iSSD. But SSD one is not available in boot loader. After I tried to install Ubuntu on SSD and restarted the machine, I was stuck at the splash screen of samsung motherboard. It kept restarting. After a quick research I thought it was because I deleted grub2 loader.

Then I tried to repartition and install again. I put 500 MB /boot ext2 partition on HDD, 5000 MB swap area on HDD, and 24 GB / ext4 partition on SSD. And set bootloader on HDD. `But this time en error occured "grub-install /dev/sda failed"`.

So I just wanted to install Ubuntu on SSD, but failed. How could I achieved that now?

Comment: The output of `sudo fdisk -l`, and what was the error `grub-install` shown.

Comment: Could you expand your comment, i do not understand

Comment: Edit your question and add the asked output. Also, can you boot Ubuntu at all?

Comment: i could not boot Ubuntu after installation so i could not manage to access terminal

Comment: My problem solved with this answer: [answer][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/173371/21205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BIOS of the Samsung NP530U4C does not allow booting from the SSD drive (/dev/sda). When you do an install you can install Ubuntu to /dev/sda but you will have to install grub to the hard drive at /dev/sdb. In the BIOS you will also need to disable fastboot, disable secure mode, and change boot mode to CMS.

Comment: I updated my question. The SSD drive is mapped to /dev/sdb and HDD is mapped to /dev/sda. And in BIOS i can disable fastboot but there is no settings to disable secure mode and change boot mode. As i stated in the question i could not installed grub on hard drive