# Can't install Ubuntu on Dell G3 3779

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, system-installation, dell, 19.04

it is the first time I'm trying to install Linux on my Dell G3 that I have 3 months ago. Well, when I bought it already come with a Linux (16.04 LTS) but in a HDD. I have made a little upgrade installing a SSD on it. Well, my first choice was trying install Ubuntu with no dualboot. I'v installed linux sucessfully, but when I try to start the system my PC didn't recognize as a boot option, so appears a message saying "No bootable device found". I have tried it with 16.04, 18.04 and last realease (19.04). All of them occured the same thing.
After some guides in the internet, which includes:

- https://www.todoespacoonline.com/w/2015/05/instalar-ubuntu-e-windows-em-dual-boot-guia-definitivo/,
- https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.dionysopoulos.me/portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd/amp/
- [Installation of Ubuntu 16.04 from a USB drive freezes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861743/installation-of-ubuntu-16-04-from-a-usb-drive-freezes)
- ["grub-install /dev/sda failed" for dual-boot with Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886367/grub-install-dev-sda-failed-for-dual-boot-with-windows-10)
- https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/G3-17-3779-Ubuntu-18-04-LTS/m-p/6106352#M16388

I still getting the same error. I trying now make a dualboot.
Please, help me install Ubuntu on my PC. What I'm doing wrong?

If you guys need anything, let me know. I'm really new on installing Linux.

Comment: did you install windows after installing ubuntu?

Comment: I installed Windows before Linux, although, I already installed Linux before and then Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my issue solved after some tries.
To whomever this may concern I've solved by following the steps below:

- Installed Windows on a part of my SSD (I'd separated half of my total memory to each system)
- On Windows, I installed a programm called 'Universal USB Installer' (only works on Windows)
- Downloaded a Linux ISO from the Ubuntu site
- On Universal USB Installer I've created a bootable Pen Drive by setting the options:
  [image with the options setted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUoc6.jpg)
- After created the bootable pen drive I've turned off the system and then restart my PC selecting the pen drive as boot.
- Installed Linux normally on the second part of my SDD (creating a SWAP and A root directory in advanced options)
- And then every thing works perfectly after doing this (with dual boot) hehe

Note: I've followed a tutorial to get this conclusion:
[link to the tutorial](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/)

That's it!