# after formating Windows partition it is still showing up in dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: boot

I installed ubuntu a long time ago along side with windows 10, on an 240gb ssd, I have another 1TB HDD that I split into 2 partitions. One for ubuntu and one for windows.

Today I wanted to delete windows permanently so I formatted the partition that has windows on it .

I restarted the laptop but then noticed the it's still there on the dual boot menu .

So I formatted the 1TB incase there are some boot files there , but nothing changed.

I formatted all the partitions and reinstalled Ubuntu, and I still have the same problem.

Any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: You may be seeing UEFI boot entries which you can remove with efibootmgr. And may need to remove /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP, or UEFI may add entry again. UEFI usually finds Windows but not other systems in ESP. https://askubuntu.com/questions/794725/can-i-remove-windows-boot-manager-from-dedicated-ubuntu-computer

Comment: I saw your comments too late , i tried again to install ubuntu and now I have another  error it says Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed fatal error

Comment: @MichaelSamer Have you seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u)?

Comment: @MichaelSamer Also, according to [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/ubuntu-16-04-server-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-4175597286/): *"Mistery is actually solved. We had to create a small EFI partition on the drives for the UEFI"*

Comment: @MichaelSamer Also [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub) is another question with answers to the same error.

Comment: @MichaelSamer Make sure that `/dev/sda` is the correct disk (even if `/dev/sda` was the correct disk when Ubuntu was installed). Sometimes during installation, the disks are named differently and the installation USB is *sometimes* `/dev/sda`. Running commands like `blkid` and `lsblk` can help you determine which disk is what.

Comment: I guess the answer may depend on if you have a UEFI system or not.

Comment: If you tried to reinstall in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode and do not have a required bios_grub partition you get a grub install error. But if UEFI, it should install into ESP that Windows is using. Unless ESP is now corrupt and needs chkdsk from Windows or dosfsck from Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your efforts, I managed to solve this problem by entering the BIOS and changing the settings to default then changed the boot to legacy. and saved it.
then everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the "dual boot" menu is `grub` and you formatted the 1TB after you reinstalled Ubuntu, then you need to update `grub` by running the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: There is another problem now , it says Executing 'grub-install/dev/sda' failed this is a fatal error.. I was trying to install ubuntu again

Answer (score 0):

Use grub-customizer to delete, change boot menu
https://itsfoss.com/grub-customizer-ubuntu/