# grub-install failed

Tags: 22.04

I currently experience issue with the installation of ubuntu 22 with my USB stick. The error message during the installation is as of the following

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda

Executing 'grub-install /dev/sda' failed
```

I did search online and tried the solution others provided. None of them seem to work in my case. I thought there was something wrong with my USB stick. Then I tried the Ubuntu 20 with the same USB stick and everything works expected.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I receive the error 'grub-install /dev/sda failed' while attempting to install Ubuntu as the computer's only OS.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143678/i-receive-the-error-grub-install-dev-sda-failed-while-attempting-to-install-u)

Comment: I tried the USB version, `Try Ubuntu` button and then `Install Ubuntu` from the desktop icon. It did not work