# Unable to install GRUB in dev/sdb

Tags: 12.04, grub2, bios

I'm having trouble while installing Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) (overwriting win7). Afterwards, I encountered (similar to this one -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/62051...o-install-grub):

```
'Unable to install GRUB in dev/sdb'
 Executing 'grub-install/dev/sdb'
 This is a fatal error!
```

The installation finished and the PC was required to reboot. Afterwards, I never got past the bios screen (where the screen indicates that it is loading something; booting a CDROM, a USB, or so on). Actually, just stuck to the bios. I was unable to boot from any device (CDROM, HDD)

*I am using a gigabyte motherboard(GA-EP31-DS3L). Thanks!

I have also just tried using another hard drive just in case I have hardware issues.. but it's working smoothly. Although, I haven't tried installing Ubuntu on the hard drive I was referring to.

P.S: I used a CD to install Ubuntu.

Comment: After getting the installation error, check /var/log/syslog for more details and edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This might be solved by running boot-repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

It should either reinstall Grub correctly, or give you some helpful info you can add to this question so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround (Ubuntu 14.04.1): unplug all hard drives except for the one that Ubuntu is being installed on.  That stopped Ubuntu from installing on one disk and grub installing (well, failing to install) on another.